# Trouble compiling mozlz4 for linux

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to compile mozlz4 from github and I'm getting the following errors:

```
mozlz4.c(.text+0x18c): undefined reference to 'LZ4_compressBound'
mozlz4.c(.text+0xlf5): undefined reference to 'LZ4_compressBound'
mozlz4.c(.text+0x206): undefined reference to 'LZ4_compress_default'
```

It requires pkg-config and liblz4-dev which I have installed.
I have tried setting

```
CPATH, LIBRARY_PATH, & LD_LIBRARY_PATH
to /usr/include
and then to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu with no success.
```

I have also tried copying liblz4.a, liblz4.pc, liblz4.so, liblz4.so.1, liblz4.so.1.7.1, lz4.h, lz4frame.h, & lz4hc.h to the directory where the mozlz4.c, mozlz4.h, and unmozlz4.c files are located also with no success.

It has been many years since I have tried to compile source code on linux and I'm stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated. :D

https://github.com/pjanouch/mozlz4
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
GNU C Compiler version 5.4.0 20160609

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `gcc -o mozlz4 mozlz4.c -llz4` to compile mozlz4 and `gcc -o unmozlz4 unmozlz4.c -llz4` to compile unmozlz4